# change date format in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have a dateFormat in my onLoad function.Its format is like `"Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2016"`.I need to change it to `dd/mm/yy format`.

My jsp field where i have to display the date

```
<input type="hidden" id="dateFormat" value="${per.ArrDate}">
```

My onLoad method

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert("inside onload");
  var dateFormat=$('#dateFormat').val();
  alert($.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', new Date(dateFormat)));
});
```

How to change to `"dd/mm/yy"` format for the above input `"Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2016"`.Any help will be highly appreciable.

Comment: which type of formate u want?

Comment: dd/mm/yy is the format i want

Comment: Have server send valid ISO date string or you will need to write a parser yourself to be able to convert to date

Comment: @charlietfl Server send a valid date format.ie "Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2016" i have to convert it to dd/mm/yy format.

Comment: no, that is clearly not a valid date string format that javascript Date recognizes. Try it yourself with `new Date()` and pass in your date string

Comment: yeah ...i tried that format ,but it returns nan/nan/nan ....Due to that i have done it using jstl....

Answer (score 0):

Use this: [https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat](http://jquery-dateFormat)

```
 document.write($.format.date("Wed Jan 13 10:43:41 CET 2010", "dd~MM~yyyy"));
```